# Is it 2 character search possible in lucence

Tags: java, algorithm, lucene, full-text-search, search-engine

Hi i have a question about lucence search 
Is it possible to search a 2 character from file using lucence search

For ex. if there are names like "karthik test" is it possible to search for "ka" or "te" in lucence. If so kindly provide a code piece..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using [wildcards](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard%20Searches).

Feed your [QueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParser.html) with `te*`, and it will generate a query that starts for a `te` prefix with any suffix.

Comment: is it causes any performance issue when there are large amount of data?

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

```
    private List search(String word, IndexSearcher searcher, Date fromDate, Date toDate, int skip, int noOfRecords) throws Exception {
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        BooleanQuery.Builder finalQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
        List results = null;
        
        for(String key : keyUtil.getAllKeys()) {
            if((!key.contains("Date") || !key.contains("Time"))) {
                QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(key, analyzer);
                
                Query query = queryParser.parse(word);
                finalQuery.add(query, Occur.SHOULD);
            }
        }
        
        if(fromDate != null && toDate != null) {
            Query query = NumericDocValuesField.newSlowRangeQuery("StartDate", fromDate.getTime(), toDate.getTime());
            finalQuery.add(query, Occur.MUST);
        }
        
        TopDocs hits = searcher.search(finalQuery.build(), skip + noOfRecords);
        results = new ArrayList();
        if(hits.totalHits.value > 0) {
            int count = 0;
            for (ScoreDoc sd : hits.scoreDocs) {
                if(count >= skip) {
                    Document d = searcher.doc(sd.doc);
                    results.add(d.get("storePath"));
                }
                count ++;
            }
        }
        
        analyzer.close();
        return results;
    }
```

You can always use RegEx pattern with with attribute "word". Like

```
 * someWord *
```